# Delphi 2007, Indy - Is a variable declared in a TidTCPServer thread safe in contexts?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, indy, delphi-2007, tcpserver

If I have a `TidTCPServer` instance and I declare a `TFormatSettings` and populate it in the `Create` routine, is it safe to reference this variable (e.g. call `Format ('%1.6f', [SomeReal], AFormatSettings])` in the thread's `Execute` method, when there might be more than one context executing?

If not, how might I make thread-safe references?

Answer (score 3):

It is thread-safe as long as you are modifying `AFormatSettings` only when no threads are accessing it (such as initializing it before activating the server), and the threads are only reading from it.  `Format()` does not modify the `TFormatSettings` that is passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ever in doubt about thread safety, you could create the following function and use it in place of Format.

```
ThdSafeFormat(const aFormat: string; const aArgs: array of const): string;
var
  FormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
begin
  GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, FormatSettings);
  Result := Format(aFormat, aArgs, FormatSettings);
end;
```